# varchar(2000) -> varchar(max) results in row size overflow

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to change the type of a column from varchar(2000) to varchar(max). This results in a "row size (8090) exceeds the maximum number of bytes per row (8060)." error, which makes no sense to me. I am on SQL server 2005.

Comment: why would not you try alter table ... varchar(8060) ?

Comment: @heximal, presumably because he wants to use an unbounded data type rather than one that limits you to 8060 bytes.

Comment: Could you post your `alter table` statement ? `VARCHAR(MAX)` can hold up to 2GB -1byte data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindda solved. Initially we could not use the designer to alter the column (timeout issue), and altered the table manually, which failed. Finally we tried copying the designer-generated scripts and running them manually (thereby bypassing the timeout). Success. Still makes no sense though, but now it works :o)